# Принять JSON на стороне JS

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Добрый день. Возникла такая проблема.
Нужно из списка  выбрать имя таблицы из БД, отправить его в php файл, выполнить запрос на выборку всех столбцов из таблицы, отправить имена этих столбцов обратно и сгенерировать поля по количеству этих самых столбцов(делаю добавление записей в админке).
Вот AJAX

```
<script>
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    var element = document.createElement("input");
var z = document.getElementsByName("tables");
    $('select[name="tables"]').change(function(){
            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                dataType : "json", // Тип данных, который ожидаем получить
                url: "admin_add_script.php", // url where to submit the request
                success : function(result) {
element.id = "hi";
parent.appendChild(element);
$('#inputs').html(result[0].column_name);
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        }
    );
</script>
```

Отправляю выбранное значение.
Файл PHP

```
<?php
include "../php/connect_bd.php";
    $data = array();
    $post = $_POST['tables'];
    $sql = "
select COLUMN_NAME 
from information_schema.columns
where  TABLE_NAME = '" . $post . "'
";
    $result = pg_query($connect, $sql);
    while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo $json;
```

Запрос выполняется нормально. Получаю вот такой массив:

```
[{"column_name":"id"},{"column_name":"primary_name"},{"column_name":"secondary_name"},{"column_name":"link"}]
```

Но вот дальше на стороне JS не выходит нормально принять.
Делал аналогичным способом поиск и всё работало. Тут же ошибка:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'column_name' of undefined
    at Object.success (admin_add.html:66)
    at i (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4)
```

Помогите найти ошибку

Comment: ну подключили jquery дак используйте в полной мере, зачем вам это `document.getElementByName('tables')` если это эквивалент `$("tables")` ?

Comment: откройте панель разработчика в браузере ф12, включите отладчик и посмотрите что вам там в success функцию приходит.

Comment: Приходит пустой массив) Наверное, в этом проблема)

Comment: Разобрался. Я как-то совсем забыл про serialized. Добавил его и заработало)

Comment: честно сказать не понял о чем вы,  но можете опубликовать ответ на свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var form = $('#form').serialize();
```

Добавление данной строчки решило проблему